# Len & Substitute

Tags: excel, vba

I just struggling out with some VBA code.

```
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "One or more emails adresses?"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=len(RC[-7])-len(substitute(RC[-7];""@"";""""))"
```

I just want insert to cell N2 formula: `=LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2;"@";""))`

Where I had made a mistake?
Thanks for any help

Comment: you are separating the arguments of substitute with semicolons. You need commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,""@"",""""))"
```

Edit: following comments

You can use the following to avoid selecting cells

```
Range("N1").Value = "One or more emails adresses?"
Range("N2").Formula = "=LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,""@"",""""))"
```

Comment: Or `Range("N2").Formula.....`.  `Range("N2").Select` is just not needed.  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Thanks @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I think I need to be a little nicer :)